# Dictionary looping getting every value

Tags: python, dictionary, traversal

without any imports

```
# given
deps = {'W': ['R', 'S'], 'C': [], 'S': ['C'], 'R': ['C'], 'F': ['W']}
prob = {'C': [0.5], 'R': [0.2, 0.8], 'S': [0.5, 0.1], 'W': [0.01, 0.9, 0.9,     0.99], 'F' : [0.4, 0.3]}
k = 'F'
# want to return:  L = [[0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], [0.4, 0.3]]


# attempt

L = []

for i in deps[k]:
    s = i
    while(deps[s] != []):
        L.append(prob[s])
        s = deps[s]
print(L)
```

I'm having trouble figuring this out. So given 2 dictionaries: dependents and probability I wish to traverse through a select point and set every value so for the above example I chose 'F'.

It would first go into the deps of 'F', find 'W' and then check the deps of that being ['R', 'S'] then check 'R' seeing that the depedent of 'R' is 'C' and 'C' does not a depedent so we stop at 'R' and append its probability into L.

```
 [[0.2, 0.8]]
```

then we go into S and do the same thing

```
[[0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1]]
```

then we're done with that and we're back at W

```
[[0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99]]
```

and finally since we're done with W we get the prob dict of F

```
[[0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], [0.4, 0.3]]
```

My code fails when theres more than one dependent value. Not sure how to wrap my head around that. Trying to make a function that will do this given deps and prob and value of k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a stack-based depth-first search to traverse the dependency tree. It adds probabilities at each step iff. the node has dependencies, and then simply reverses the list at the end.

```
def prob_list(root):
    nodes_to_visit = [root]
    prob_list = []

    while nodes_to_visit:
        curr = nodes_to_visit.pop()
        print(f"Visiting {curr}")

        if deps[curr]:
            prob_list.append(prob[curr])
            for dep in deps[curr]:
                nodes_to_visit.append(dep)

    return list(reversed(prob_list))

print(prob_list("F"))  # [[0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], [0.4, 0.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem with a `while` loop that keeps looking to see if you've used all the values you've recursively found. You can use a structure like:

```
deps = {'W': ['R', 'S'], 'C': [], 'S': ['C'], 'R': ['C'], 'F': ['W']}
# out = ['F', 'W', 'R', 'S']
prob = {'C': [0.5], 'R': [0.2, 0.8], 'S': [0.5, 0.1], 'W': [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], 'F': [0.4, 0.3]}
k = 'F'

L = []
my_list = []
found_all = False

def get_values(dep_dictionary, prob_dict, start_key):
    used_keys = []
    keys_to_use = [start_key]
    probability = []
    # build a list of linked values from deps dictionary
    while used_keys != keys_to_use:
        print('used: {}'.format(used_keys))
        print('to use: {}'.format(keys_to_use))
        for i in range(len(keys_to_use)):
            if keys_to_use[i] not in used_keys:
                new_keys = dep_dictionary[keys_to_use[i]]
                if len(new_keys):
                    for sub_key in new_keys:
                        if sub_key not in keys_to_use:
                            keys_to_use.append(sub_key)
                    used_keys.append(keys_to_use[i])
                else:
                    del keys_to_use[i]
    # at this point used_keys = ['F', 'W', 'R', 'S']
    for key in used_keys:
        probability.append(prob_dict[key])
    print(probability)

get_values(deps, prob, k)
```

Which outputs:

```
used: []
to use: ['F']
used: ['F']
to use: ['F', 'W']
used: ['F', 'W']
to use: ['F', 'W', 'R', 'S']
used: ['F', 'W', 'R', 'S']
to use: ['F', 'W', 'R', 'S', 'C']
[[0.4, 0.3], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], [0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1]]
```

Where you can see the output is correct (`[[0.4, 0.3], [0.01, 0.9, 0.9, 0.99], [0.2, 0.8], [0.5, 0.1]]`), however it is not in the exact same order, but it doesn't sound like that should be a huge issue. If it is, you can always re-splice it into a dictionary by adjusting the

```
for key in used_keys:
    probability.append(prob_dict[key])
```

bit such that `probability` is a dictionary also. You can also take the `print()` statements out, they were just there to debug and show visually what is going on within the loop. You also would probably have the function `return probability` instead of printing it, but I'll leave that to your discretion!